# Minecraft Villagers vanish

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After winning a raid, all my villagers are gone from the village, although they were not even killed by pillagers. Does anyone have any idea of whats happening?

Comment: were they scared away or something? Interesting question, although we need details of what happened in that night so we can evaluate the cause. if the world has cheats you can respawn them with eggs, but I see that's not available in your case.

Comment: 1. it wasnt night... 2. it was a normal raid with vindicators, pillagers, and the beast thing,,, nothing else. 3. after i won the raid, the villagers will still there, then i went to loot some structures, hence after i came back, i found them not being there except one of them that i had locked inside cobblestones.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities to what may have happened to your villagers:

1. **They escaped the structure they were contained in.** Villagers will automatically try to find the nearest route to their job site, which is a job block (such as a fletching table or a lectern). The ravager may have broken a few blocks of the wall, allowing the villagers to freely explore.
2. **They have temporarily turned invisible.** There are a few bugs in earlier versions where mobs have been known to disappear and reappear randomly. Although this is unlikely, we don't know your version so we can't rule it out as a possibility.
3. **They have entered a Nether portal.** If you built a portal in the structure they were in, they might have ran into the portal and been teleported to the Nether.

Comment: ok thanks, probably its first one

Answer (score -3):

What happens is that villagers despawn without a name tag, so name your mob so that it doesn't just dissapear.

Comment: The [wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Villager) says they never despawn by themselves. Besides, I dont think you can normally nametag them, since RMB opens the trading GUI.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Using a name tag on a villager does not open the trading menu. See [the wiki page trivia](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Villager#Trivia)
But you are correct, a villager does not just despawn.